# Why is onRestoreInstanceState called for a view when the activity is destroyed?

Tags: android

In the stacktrace below you can notice that as a result of the activity being destroyed, the view's onRestoreInstanceState is called. Why is this necessary?

```
    at com.mypackage.MyView.onRestoreInstanceState(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:13758)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2889)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2895)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2895)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:13736)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.o.onDestroy(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6189)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3778)
    ... 10 more
```

**EDIT**:

The [View.onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)) receives whatever [View.onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState()) produced. The documentation for onSaveInstanceState says: "Hook allowing a view to generate a representation of its internal state that can later be used to create a new instance with that same state." - When an onDestroy is performed there is no need to recreate the views, so then why is onRestoreInstanceState called?

Comment: What Android version are you on?

Comment: And what is the Exception?

Comment: The exception is irrelevant. The Android version is from Android 4.0.3 to Android 5.1. This particular one is from: Moto X (gen2) (victara) according to the Google Play Developer Console.

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion=22 in build.gradle. I'm saying the exception is irrelevant because it's a NPE in my custom code in the onRestoreInstanceState of my custom view - I fixed it now and the exception does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `onRestoreInstanceState` of your **Fragment** happens as part of the `onDestroy` of your **Activity**.

This is the behavior in `FragmentManagerImpl`:

```
void moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle, boolean keepActive) {
    //...
    case Fragment.CREATED:
    if (newState > Fragment.CREATED) {
    //...
        f.performActivityCreated(f.mSavedFragmentState);
        if (f.mView != null) {
            f.restoreViewState(f.mSavedFragmentState);
        }
        f.mSavedFragmentState = null;
    }
}
```

If the state of the fragment is changed (moved) and the fragment's view is not null then restoreViewState is always called as part of this process.

Maybe you are not calling `super.onDestroy()` as the first statement in `onDestroy`?

Comment: The View.onRestoreInstanceState receives whatever View.onSaveInstanceState produced. The documentation for onSaveInstanceState says: "Hook allowing a view to generate a representation of its internal state that can later be used to create a new instance with that same state." - When an onDestroy is performed there is no need to recreate the views, so then why is View.onRestoreInstanceState called? Could you please detail in your answer, Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Maybe you are not calling `super.onDestroy()` as the first statement in `onDestroy`?

Comment: What line did you remove from the stacktrace?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the entire trace.

Comment: What research have you done to answer your own question?

Comment: Why are you asking me that?

Comment: You ask a question and I see no effort on your side to try answering the yourself or point out where you are stuck finding a solution. The only thing I see is you looking at the javadoc for one method in the entire stacktrace. Yet, you fail to provide a complete stacktrace or provide some code to reproduce your behavior. Therefore I don't know how you expect anyone to answer your question. FragmentManagerImpl is one of the most notorious classes in the Android SDK, where even debugging it with code at hand is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question should be: Why is `savedInstanceState` *not* `null` after fragment is destroyed?